# Адаптивная картинка: получение параметра height картинки

Tags: jquery, изображения, вёрстка

Добрый вечер! При изменении формата разрешения изменяется параметр height для картинки.
**Как получить измененный параметр height, который вычисляется из widht?**

```
<img id="picBB" style="width: 100%" src="../images/map/fight/5/2.jpg" /><div id="elements"></div>
```

Т.е нужно получить высоту картинку и передать это значение блоку с ID elements. 
Пробовал load, но получаю ответ -10.

```
$("#picBB").load(function(){
    alert($( this ).height()); // -10
});
```

Comment: попробуйте [outerheight](https://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/), если не получится сделайте jsfiddle демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Спасибо, но оказалось проблема совсем в другом... Блок в котором находится данная картинка была изначально скрыта, поэтому ответ был 0 :)